# client.catch is not a function and role keeps making "new role" instead of name I specify?

Tags: javascript, node.js, client, roles, discord.js

I might just be missing something simple, but I've never had this error before and I don't think I edited it enough to cause this problem since it was last functional. The code block below keeps giving me this error at the top of the file:

```js
(node:17592) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: client.catch is not a function
```

I have specified `client = new Discord.Client();`

The other issue I am having is that I am trying to get the role that is being made by the bot to be the name of the two players/users (challenger vs target format) after the target has accepted the challenge posed by the challenger. It just makes a role named "new role" instead. Any help with either of these problems?

```js
if (message.channel.id === '541736552582086656') return challenged.send("Do you accept the challenge? Please reply with 'accept' or 'deny'.")
  .then((newmsg) => {
    newmsg.channel.awaitMessages(response => response.content, {
      max: 1,
      time: 150000,
      errors: ['time'],
    }).then((collected) => {
        // Grabs the first (and only) message from the collection.
        const reply = collected.first();

        if (reply.content === 'accept'){
          reply.channel.send(`You have ***accepted *** the challenge from ${challenger}. Please wait while your battlefield is made...`);
          message.author.send(`${target} has accepted your challenge! Please wait while the channel is made for your brawl...`)
            var server = message.guild;
            var permsName = `${target} vs ${challenger}`;
            var name = `${target} vs ${challenger}`;
            message.guild.createRole({
                data: {
                    name: permsName,
                    hoist: true,
                    color: "#00fffa",
                    permissions: [] }
            }).then(role => {
                target.addRole(data, permsName)
                challenger.addRole(role, permsName)


                // client.catch error occurring below
                .catch(error => client.catch(error))
            }).catch(error => client.catch(error)).then(
            server.createChannel(name, "text")).then(
                (channel) => {
                    channel.setParent("542070913177485323")
          })
        } else if (reply.content === 'deny') {
          reply.channel.send("You have ***denied *** the challenge.") 
        } else {
          reply.channel.send("Your response wasn't valid.");
        }
      })
   })
}
module.exports.help = {
    name: "challenge"
}
```

I have tried looking up the problem and I don't see anything that has helped so far with either issue. They might be related since the catch is after the add role part? Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Take a look at the [createRole example](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=createRole) given in the docs. As for the `client.catch` error, it occurs because a Discord Client does not have a catch function again as stated [by the docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client) (unless you have declared a catch function for the client yourself).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Curious if there's a template you copied for this bot? The `Discord.Client` object does not have any `catch` method, so calling `client.catch()` is not going to work.

To clarify, this is fine:

```
challenger.addRole(role, permsName)
.catch(error => /* do something with this error */);
```

What can you do with the error? You could print it to console, I suppose:

```
challenger.addRole(role, permsName)
.catch(error => console.error(error));
```

But you can't call `client.catch(error)`, because that's not a real method - you can check out the docs for the Client object [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client).

Regarding the role name, you just have a small error: you don't want to wrap your options object in `{ data: }`, your options object *is* the data. Just pass them in directly, like so:

```
message.guild.createRole({
    name: permsName,
    hoist: true,
    color: "#00fffa",
    permissions: []
}).then(role => {
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Yes! That did wonders! And yeah, as I've been trying to get this to work, I have been using some templates. That was definitely my problem. I'm also not sure why I didn't notice I didn't actually need "data" there in the first place! Thanks so much!